# Using Jupyter/IPython as a lightweight report generating engine?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, knitr

We have a codebase that uses Rmarkdown/knitr to generate reports, but we're trying to convert from R to Python.

Although there are projects like [PWeave](https://github.com/mpastell/Pweave), upon researching I wondered if we could use Jupyter instead due to being more mature and having the added benefit of the interactive notebooks when developing the report templates.

My question is, is Jupyter feasible as a lightweight pdf report generator? Basically using it as an advanced templating engine.

Can I run Jupyter in a lightweight/headless manner, where I only want the output file and don't care about the interactivity?

Lightweight because eventually this would be deployed to a server to generate the reports

Comment: Interesting question; my guess is "probably so". However, perhaps it's possible to tell knitr to run Python instead of R on any embedded code -- something to explore. Anyway, since this is a discussion question, it's considered off topic for SO. I think probably a Jupyter user forum would be a better audience. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: FYI you can run code from several other languages, including python, with knitr: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/other-languages.html